# Generic Xinput controller not detected properly in Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: kubuntu, hardware, 23.04, joystick, xbox-360

I've been trying to use a generic Xinput joystick (Redragon Harrow) in a fresh install of Kubuntu 23.04. The first time I plugged it in it worked like a charm (it even was detected as an Xbox controller), but every time after that, it's being detected as "ShanWan PC/PS3/Android" and the Joystick's rumble doesn't work anymore.

Does someone know what to do to fix this?